# Run a program from PowerShell with timeout

Tags: powershell, process, timeout

I'll write a script that runs a program and wait for it finished. But if the program is not finished within a specified time I want that the program is killed.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here is a script which does that. See [Windows PowerShell Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/powershell/archive/2007/01/16/managing-processes-in-powershell.aspx) for the original example.

```
$p = [diagnostics.process]::start("notepad.exe")
if ( ! $p.WaitForExit(1000) ) 
  { echo "Notepad did not exit after 1000ms"; $p.kill() }
```

Comment: On PowerShell 2.0 you can replace that first line with `$p = Start-Process Notepad -passthru'