# How to know when a command isn't responding in powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a powershell script which launch a command line utility [DacIESvcCli.exe](http://sqldacexamples.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Import%20Export%20Service%20Client)

DacIESvcCli.exe sends me a response and when I receive it I take the status, which can be "Running" or "Completed"

My problem is that sometimes the call hangs and I never get a response. The following script can run 3 days without interruption.
**How can I prevent this from happening?**

```
$myCounter = 0
while($myCounter -lt 5){
Write "start of the while counter : "  $myCounter
$exportResponse = C:\DAC\DacIESvcCli.exe -s "myserver.database.windows.net" -u "mylogin@myserver" -p "mypassword" -requestid 'e1e34eee-1aaa-4cc9-8c48-3a2239fe1bff' -status
$exportStatus = $exportResponse[10].split(" ")[1].toString() 
Write $exportStatus
$myCounter++
}
```

Here is the output

```
start of the while counter :
0
Completed
start of the while counter :
1
Completed
start of the while counter :
2
Completed
start of the while counter :
3
_
```

... and it never ends.

Comment: check these cmdlets :
start-job wait-job check out this post for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4650913/how-to-timeout-powershell-function-call

Comment: Thanks I found out how to do it with your answer

Comment: @TimPost - why did you delete user1027785's answer?  From the comments (and comment voting) above, it apparently was enough to answer the OP's question.  It might be nice in the future to see a reason for deleting somebody else's answer. I'm not trying to be a jerk. I would like to learn when it is appropriate to delete an answer.

Comment: Nobody deleted user1027785's answer. He just answered directly in the comment.

Comment: Would you mind posting the resulting script?

Answer (score 0):

Here is part of my script for [Travis Heseman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/175094/travis-heseman)

```
  param($username, $password, $serverName, $requestId)
  $consecutiveFailedAttempt = 0 

while( $exportStatus -ne "Completed" -and $exportStatus -ne "Failed" -and $exportStatus -ne "TooLong"){  
    if($exportStatus -ne "FirstRun"){ 
        Start-Sleep -m 60000 # Wait 1 min  
    }

    $currentNow = Get-Date 

    $job = Start-Job {  param($s, $u, $p, $r) C:\DAC\DacIESvcCli.exe -s $s  -User $u  -p $p  -requestid $r -status } -ArgumentList @($serverName, $username, $password, $requestId)


    Wait-Job $job -Timeout 60 # if the command takes longer than 60 sec we timeout and retry
    Stop-Job $job 
    $exportResponse = Receive-Job $job
    Remove-Job $job 

    if($exportResponse[10]){
        $exportStatus = $exportResponse[10].split(" ")[1].toString()  
        $consecutiveFailedAttempt = 0;
    }else{
        $currentNow = Get-Date
        $whileMessage = "Time out we retry " + $currentNow   
        $whileMessage | Out-File $File -append
        $exportStatus = "Unknown"
        $consecutiveFailedAttempt++;
    }

    if($consecutiveFailedAttempt -gt 10){
        $exportStatus = "TooLong"
    }

}
# do wantever you want  with the export status
```